# Swagger launch from DockerCompose takes 5+ minutes only when using Serilog w/Log Level Warning

Tags: .net, docker, swagger, serilog

I have a .net 8 minimal API web project using ef core.

I have docker compose configured and I'm using Serilog and Swagger UI.

Whenever I configure my Serilog settings to use an Override for Microsoft as anything other than "informational", it takes ~5 minutes for Swagger UI to launch the browser. However everything in the app works perfectly fine and I can navigate to the swagger page on my localhost without issue and make API calls.

See my appsettings.Developmnent.json

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Error",
      "System": "Error"
    }
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    { "Name": "Console" },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "/app/Logs/log-.txt",
        "rollingInterval": "Day"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
  "Properties": {
    "Application": "myapp"
  }
```

My appsettings.json is similar but Microsoft and System are set to Error. Setting everything the same doesn't work unless it's Informational.

I've tried with and without the "UseSerilogRequestLogging" extension method as well.

Here is how I load serilog:

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));
```

Here is how I load swagger and other Serilog setting:

```
public static class SwaggerConfiguration
{
    public static void ConfigureSwagger(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Class for application initialization
/// </summary>
public static class ApplicationInitialization
{
    public static void Initialize(WebApplication app)
    {
        EndpointMapper.MapAllEndpoints(app);

        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
    }
}
```

Here's the launch with timestamp:

```
17:17:36:967    docker exec -i 27c03df1adf3 /bin/sh -c "if PID=$(pidof dotnet); then kill $PID; fi"
17:17:41:924    ========== Debugging ==========
17:17:42:592    docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/myapp$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
17:17:42:749    27c03df1adf3
17:22:44:600    Launching https://localhost:59757/swagger ...
```

Here is what I've found in my log file:

```
2023-12-18 22:12:42.363 +00:00 [INF] Now listening on: http://[::]:8080
2023-12-18 22:12:42.364 +00:00 [INF] Now listening on: https://[::]:8081
2023-12-18 22:12:42.366 +00:00 [INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-12-18 22:12:42.367 +00:00 [INF] Hosting environment: Development
2023-12-18 22:12:42.367 +00:00 [INF] Content root path: /app
2023-12-18 22:12:42.830 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:59757/swagger/index.html - null null
2023-12-18 22:12:43.000 +00:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:59757/swagger/index.html - 200 null text/html;charset=utf-8 170.7554ms
2023-12-18 22:12:43.159 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:59757/swagger/v1/swagger.json - null null
2023-12-18 22:12:43.166 +00:00 [INF] No action descriptors found. This may indicate an incorrectly configured application or missing application parts. To learn more, visit https://aka.ms/aspnet/mvc/app-parts
2023-12-18 22:12:43.273 +00:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:59757/swagger/v1/swagger.json - 200 null application/json;charset=utf-8 113.6402ms
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having similar issues. I've read elsewhere to disable swagger's syntax highlighting for performance gains, but that hasn't helped me.

That is, in Program.cs: `app.UseSwaggerUI(o =>o.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems.Add("syntaxHighlight", false));`